# How do I open facebook url with app assuming that I can't get global userId via graph api

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get permission to access user's public profile so I can provide a link  to this person's profile to other people using an app.

within the api response, we have a "link", but it is a https://facebook.com/... link, and not some intent link like `fb://profile/<id>`

So how can I create this link without global user id and username?

I also tried to use `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=<link>` but it redirects me to my own facebook home page (feed)

Thank you!

Comment: plse refer to below link:- https://medium.com/@shrawan25.sharma/urgent-facebook-sdk-app-update-to-retain-permission-access-a256b76e5bd5

Comment: @Shrawan thanks for it. but my point here is other. There is two things that bothers me:

1. The public url that facebook give you expires.
    In my application I want users to exchange their facebook profile as much as they want. With this link it is impossible.
2. The public url that facebook give you can't be open in app (android/ios), only browser.
    For user experience this is awful... no one wants to login in browser if they are already logged in in app

But I get your point and it is very clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dhiogo's anwser is not working anymore. Facebook's API retrieves an user_id when the user authenticates within your application. So all you have to do is use this user_id like this:

```
fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/profile.php&user_id=[user_id]
```

Comment: Cool! It worked! The only problem with this solution is that this user_id is scoped and have some limitations (expiration). But depending on your application, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a closed bug that Facebook didn't fixed: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332195860270199

**But I could find a solution**!!! All you have to do is to get the scoped link that facebook graph api generates (link permission) and replace the `https://facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/` with `fb://profile/?app_scoped_user_id/` leaving the rest of the link as it is.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hey, I am struggling for this issue for months , your answer didn't work for me.Did you find any other solution? I have `user_link` granted and can get user link bay field 'link',however I am getting this error  [message](https://imgur.com/vWvcpIH).But the strange thing is it's working if the user whose page I am trying to open has mutual friend with me.